# Design pattern for combining separate branches into common structure

Tags: python, design-patterns, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I've got applications that consist of a data loader and a data transformer. Each loader and each transformer are subclasses of an abstract base loader and an abstract base transformer, which I'll omit in the example below. There is a 1:1 mapping between the concrete loaders and transformers, i.e. is known which loader and transformer belong together.

Say we have two loaders and two transformers, handling data

```py
class Data1: ...

class Data2: ...


class Loader1:
    def get_data(self) -> Data1: ...

class Loader2:
    def get_data(self) -> Data2: ...


class Transformer1:
    def transform_data(self, data: Data1) -> None: ...

class Transformer2:
    def transform_data(self, data: Data2) -> None: ...
```

These classes could now be combined into applications

```py
class App1:
    Loader = Loader1
    Transformer = Transformer1

class App2:
    Loader = Loader2
    Transformer = Transformer2
```

with an accompanying factory

```py
from typing import Union, Type

def make_app(use_app1: bool) -> Union[Type[App1], Type[App2]]:
    if use_app1:
        return App1
    else:
        return App2
```

This is how I'd like to use the above

```py
def main(use_app1: bool) -> None:
    app = make_app(use_app1)
    loader = app.Loader()
    data = loader.get_data()
    transformer = app.Transformer()
    transformer.transform_data(data=data)
```

However, [mypy complains](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=85632e6d75d5e74f6a6bdf470e2a8037):

```py
error: Argument "data" to "transform_data" of "Transformer1" has incompatible type "Union[Data1, Data2]"; expected "Data1"  [arg-type]
error: Argument "data" to "transform_data" of "Transformer2" has incompatible type "Union[Data1, Data2]"; expected "Data2"  [arg-type]
```

Is there some way to convince `mypy` that the branches `Loader1 -> Data1 -> Transformer1` and `Loader2 -> Data2 -> Transformer2` are separate and will not be mixed?

Is there an alternative pattern that could be used for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's a third attempt at solving this. In this attempt, I'm using abstract protocols to tell MyPy that, in fact, in a lot of these functions, it doesn't *matter* what specific type is being returned, as long as the object being returned has a certain interface.

```
from typing import Type, Protocol, cast


### ABSTRACT INTERFACES ###


class DataProto(Protocol): ...
    

class LoaderProto(Protocol):
    def get_data(self) -> DataProto: ...
    

class TransformerProto(Protocol):
    def transform_data(self, data: DataProto) -> None: ...


class AppProto(Protocol):
    Loader: Type[LoaderProto]
    Transformer: Type[TransformerProto]
    

### CONCRETE IMPLEMENTATIONS ###
    

class Data1: ...


class Data2: ...


class Loader1:
    def get_data(self) -> Data1: ...


class Loader2:
    def get_data(self) -> Data2: ...


class Transformer1:
    def transform_data(self, data: Data1) -> None: ...


class Transformer2:
    def transform_data(self, data: Data2) -> None: ...


class App1:
    Loader = Loader1
    Transformer = Transformer1


class App2:
    Loader = Loader2
    Transformer = Transformer2
    

GenericAppClassType = Type[AppProto]
    

def make_app(use_app1: bool) -> GenericAppClassType:
    if use_app1:
        return cast(GenericAppClassType, App1)
    else:
        return cast(GenericAppClassType, App2)


def main(use_app1: bool) -> None:
    app = make_app(use_app1)
    loader = app.Loader()
    data = loader.get_data()
    transformer = app.Transformer()
    transformer.transform_data(data=data)
```

Try it out on mypy playground [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=b7beca6665603d24a9989475a5137648).

Comment: Ok this now solves the issue I think. Thank you for spending so much time on this! I'd wait some days if somebody comes with a cleaner solution but if not I'd accept this one.

Comment: @BayerSe no worries! It annoyed me that I couldn't find a good solution lol.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different answer that still involves a fair amount of extra code, but at least makes a little more *sense* than adding a pointless if-else statement in there just for the type-checker. This solution uses generic abstract base classes to make it explicit to the type-checker that `Data1` and `Data2` have the same interface, etc. etc.:

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta
from typing import Union, Type, TypeVar, Any, Protocol


### ABSTRACT INTERFACES ###


class AbstractData:
    __slots__ = ()
    

class AbstractLoader(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    __slots__ = ()
    
    @abstractmethod
    def get_data(self) -> AbstractData: ...
    

D = TypeVar('D', bound=AbstractData, contravariant=True)
    

class AbstractTransformer(Protocol[D]):
    __slots__ = ()
    
    @abstractmethod
    def transform_data(self, data: D) -> None: ...


L = TypeVar('L', bound=AbstractLoader, covariant=True)
T = TypeVar('T', bound=AbstractTransformer[Any], covariant=True)


class AbstractApp(Protocol[L, T]):
    __slots__ = ()
    
    @classmethod
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def Loader(cls) -> Type[L]: ...
    
    @classmethod
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def Transformer(cls) -> Type[T]: ...
    

### CONCRETE IMPLEMENTATIONS ###
    

class Data1(AbstractData): ...


class Data2(AbstractData): ...


class Loader1(AbstractLoader):
    def get_data(self) -> Data1: ...


class Loader2(AbstractLoader):
    def get_data(self) -> Data2: ...


class Transformer1(AbstractTransformer[Data1]):
    def transform_data(self, data: Data1) -> None: ...


class Transformer2(AbstractTransformer[Data2]):
    def transform_data(self, data: Data2) -> None: ...


class App1(AbstractApp[Loader1, Transformer1]):
    Loader = Loader1
    Transformer = Transformer1


class App2(AbstractApp[Loader2, Transformer2]):
    Loader = Loader2
    Transformer = Transformer2
    

def make_app(use_app1: bool) -> Type[AbstractApp[Any, Any]]:
    if use_app1:
        return App1
    else:
        return App2


def main(use_app1: bool) -> None:
    app = make_app(use_app1)
    loader = app.Loader()
    data = loader.get_data()
    transformer = app.Transformer()
    transformer.transform_data(data=data)
```

Comment: Sorry to say this does not work either :-(.

There's a typo in the overload:
`def make_app(use_app1: Literal[False]) -> Type[App1]:` 
should be
`def make_app(use_app1: Literal[False]) -> Type[App2]:`

With that fixed `mypy` yields
`error: Argument "data" to "transform_data" of "Transformer1" has incompatible type "Union[Data1, Data2]"; expected "Data1"`

Comment: @BayerSe I've edited my answer to take out the overloads and make the hints more generic. I think that works now; hopefully there aren't any more typos.

Comment: Now `mypy` does indeed not complain anymore. I think it primarily works because `mypy` does not really understand the logic.
For instance, adding `reveal_type(data)` to `main()` shows that mypy thinks data is of type `Any`.
Although your answer kind of solves my original problem I still have some hope that there might be a cleaner solution :-/.

Comment: @BayerSe -- Yes, you're right; if all we've accomplished is to confuse MyPy, then we've not accomplished much. I haven't any other bright ideas at the moment... it's an extremely frustrating problem!

Comment: I totally agree on your last point - I already spent many, many hours on that :-(

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that there are in fact two different signatures for your `make_app` function: one signature if `use_app1` is `True`, and another if `use_app1` is `False`. `typing.overload`, in combination with `typing.Literal`, is the solution here, as `@overload` allows us to register multiple different signatures of a function. Implementations of a function decorated with `@overload` are ignored at runtime — they are solely for the type checker — so the body of these functions can be left empty. Generally, you'll just put a literal ellipsis `...` or a docstring in the body of these functions. There must be at least one concrete implementation of the function not decorated with `@overload`, for use at runtime.

```
from typing import overload, Literal, Union, Type

App1Type = Type[App1]
App2Type = Type[App2]

@overload
def make_app(use_app1: Literal[True]) -> App1Type:
    """Signature of the function when `use_app1` is True"""

@overload
def make_app(use_app1: Literal[False]) -> App2Type:
    """Signature of the function when `use_app1` is False"""

def make_app(use_app1: bool) -> Union[App1Type, App2Type]:
    """Concrete implementation of the function, for use at runtime"""

    if use_app1:
        return App1
    else:
        return App2
```

The documentation for `typing.overload` is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload); the documentation for `typing.Literal` is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal).

---

**EDIT**: Looks like this doesn't work. You can make it work by rewriting the `main` function like this, but there must be a better way out there than doing a truly pointless `if-else` statement...

```
def main(use_app1: Literal[True, False]) -> None:
    app: Union[App1Type, App2Type]
    loader: Union[Loader1, Loader2]
    data: Union[Data1, Data2]
    transformer: Union[Transformer1, Transformer2]
    
    if use_app1:
        app = make_app(use_app1)
        loader = app.Loader()
        data = loader.get_data()
        transformer = app.Transformer()
        transformer.transform_data(data=data)
    else:
        app = make_app(use_app1)
        loader = app.Loader()
        data = loader.get_data()
        transformer = app.Transformer()
        transformer.transform_data(data=data)
```

Comment: `mypy` does not like this as well, unfortunately.
While `make_app(True)` works, `make_app(use_app1)` raises `error: No overload variant of "make_app" matches argument type "bool"  [call-overload]`

Comment: @BayerSe — I've edited my answer with a solution that works... but there must be a better way...